# Sepia Toned PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, ibooks

I know iBooks has this little nuance built in.  Has anyone figured out how to render all pages in a PDF in sepia tone?

Comment: As steipete points out, iBooks doesn't provide a customizable background for PDFs, only ePubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse iBook's epub viewer with the pdf component - with epub, you basically have html and text, and you can change the background pretty easily.

With pdf, there is no such feature, neither in iBooks nor in the Quartz parsing library.